# Неактивный контент для продажи в Google Play Console

Tags: google-play-console

В Google Play Console у контента для продажи стоит статус "Неактивно". Почему и как изменить статус я разобраться не смог. В их документации по созданию контента для продажи написано: В разделе "Статус" выберите Активно или Неактивно. Но такого пункта нигде нет. Может ли это быть связано с тем, что приложение еще проходит модерацию?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Мой недосмотр. В новой версии Статус выбирается не в отдельном выпадающем списке в настройках продукта, а в самом низу, после сохранения изменений или создания продукта
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]